# An application of partial summation to estimate the sum $\sum_{\mathbf{x}} 1/ \sqrt{x_1^4 + x_1^2x_2^2 + x_2^4 }$

Tags: number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory, integer-lattices

In an article I am reading they obtain the following 
$$
\sum_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{Z}^{2} \backslash \{0\}, \| \mathbf{x} \| \leq Z } \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^4 + x_1^2x_2^2 + x_2^4 } }
= c Z(1 + O(1/Z)),
$$
where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm and 
$$
c = \int_{\| \mathbf{t}\| \leq 1 } \frac{d \mathbf{t}}{\sqrt{t_1^4 + t_1^2t_2^2 + t_2^4 } }. 
$$ 
The only explanation is that it follows by an application of partial summation and elementary lattice point counting argument.

I am not sure how this holds and explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the sum as an estimation of the integral based on a grid size of $1/Z$.

Comment: I am not quite seeing how I can deduce the conclusion with your hint.. Any further explanation would be appreciated.. thank u...

Comment: $$\begin{align}\sum_{\mathbf x\in \Bbb Z^2 \setminus \{0\}, \|\mathbf{x}\| \le Z} \frac 1{\sqrt{x_1^4 + x_1^2x_2^2 + x_2^4}} &= \sum_{\mathbf x\in \Bbb Z^2 \setminus \{0\}, \|\mathbf{x}\| \le Z} \frac 1{Z^2\sqrt{\left(\frac{x_1}Z\right)^4 + \left(\frac{x_1}Z\right)^2\left(\frac{x_2}Z\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x_2}Z\right)^4}}\\&=\sum_{Z\mathbf t\in \Bbb Z^2 \setminus \{0\}, \|\mathbf t\| \le 1} \frac {\frac1{Z^2}}{\sqrt{t_1^4 + t_1^2t_2^2 + t_2^4}}\end{align}$$Compare that last expression to your integral. If you still don't see it, go look up the definition of the Riemann integral again.